# 3D rotation effect using multiple image frames in Javascript - how to trigger element fade in/out on certain frames?

Tags: javascript, 3d, triggers, rotation, fadein

I am using Javascript to drag and simulate rotating an image by using multiple frames showing the image in 360 degrees. I am relatively new to JavaScript and am having a hard time with the script in trying to insert a trigger that would cause overlaying images to fade in and out when certain frames (degrees) of the image are displayed. For example, when I drag, rotate and reveal the front side of the image, let's say a range of frame 10 to frame 45, 4 popup labels will fade in (simultaneously) and remain visible until I drag and rotate the image away from that range of frame, causing the labels to fade out. On the backside of the image I would like to have 3 popup labels appear once any frame within the acceptable range of frames are displayed, let's say, frames 95 through 135. Is this possible? Please see the code that I have been  working off of below:

```
  /*** configuration variables ***/
var
totalFrames = 72,
frameUrlTemplate =
'images/frames/Skeleton_[#frame].jpg'
;

/*** state variables ***/
var
rotation = 0,
lastFrameNo = -1,
dragStartRotation
;

/*** create the Uize.Widget.Drag instance ***/
var rotationViewer = page.addChild (
'rotationViewer',
Uize.Widget.Drag,
{
cancelFade:{duration:2000,curve:Uize.Curve.Rubber.easeOutBounce ()},
releaseTravel:function (speed) {
var
deceleration = 2000, // measured in pixels/s/s
duration = speed / deceleration
;
return {
duration:duration,
distance:Math.round (speed * duration / 2),
curve:function (_value) {return 1 - (_value = 1 - _value) * _value}
};
},
html:function (input) {
var
htmlChunks = [],
frameNodeIdPrefix = input.idPrefix + '-frame'
;
for (var frameNo = 0; ++frameNo <= totalFrames;) {
htmlChunks.push (
'<img' +
' id="' + frameNodeIdPrefix + frameNo + '"' +
' src="' + Uize.substituteInto (frameUrlTemplate,{frame:(frameNo < 10 ? '0' : '') + frameNo}) +'"' +
'/>'
);
}
return htmlChunks.join ('');
},
built:false
}
);

/*** wire up the drag widget with events for updating rotation degree ***/
function updateRotation (newRotation) {
rotation = ((newRotation % 360) + 360) % 360;
var frameNo = 1 + Math.round (rotation / 360 * (totalFrames - 1));
if (frameNo != lastFrameNo) {
rotationViewer.showNode ('frame'+ lastFrameNo,false);
rotationViewer.showNode ('frame'+ (lastFrameNo = frameNo));
}
}
rotationViewer.wire ({
'Drag Start':function () {dragStartRotation = rotation},
'Drag Update':function (e) {updateRotation (dragStartRotation - e.source.eventDeltaPos [0] / -2.5)}
});

/*** function for animating spin ***/
function spin (degrees,duration,curve) {
Uize.Fade.fade (updateRotation,rotation,rotation + degrees,duration,{quantization:1,curve:curve});
}

/*** initialization ***/
Uize.Node.wire (window,'load',function () {spin (-360,2700,Uize.Curve.easeInOutPow (4))});

/*** wire up the page widget ***/
page.wireUi ();
```

I'd appreciate any advice on this. Thanks!!
-Adam

Answer (score 0):

there are 3d transforms in javascrip fot html elements, even a few libaries.
if its a flat image, use that.
if its 3d you wish to simulate you already get very realistc effect with just 120 pictures.

```
 rotation = ((newRotation % 360) + 360) % 360;
 var frameNo = 1 + Math.round (rotation / 360 * (totalFrames -1));
 if (frameNo > 0 && frameNo< 60 )//code to show box
```

Comment: Thank you. I had decided to use just 72 pictures/frames to simulate 3D. The object is a 3D skeleton rendered out into 72 jpg's. Looking at the code, I can't figure out where and how to create a trigger that will fade in elements such as boxes when the image is rotated toward the front perspective within a certain range of frames. I just don't know how to write the code to make this function. I wonder if `('#fade-in',{ delay: 400, duration: 300, property:'left', start:-1400, end:0 });` might be close to the solution.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderfull world of 3d problems. this is just as fun as collission detecting. see my edited answer

Comment: I meant to write `('#fade-in',{ delay: 400, duration: 300, property:'opacity', start:0 });`

Comment: It might, but just add your frame checking code where i added it. below those lines. then determine the ranges you want to show what abnd in which ranges you want to hide things.